# Stripe checkout failing for package pricing

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, stripe-payments

I am implementing Stripe in my Laravel/Vue app and have defined 4 types of prices on a product. I am implementing a credits model where e.g:

```
1 EUR => 1 credit
3 EUR => 4 credits
4 EUR => 7 credits
7 EUR => 10 credits
```

I figured first one being a standard pricing (that one works), other 3 are defined as package pricing (e.g. 3 EUR for quantity of 4).

The flow should go like this; user picks from a slider how much credits would he like to purchase (1, 4, 7, 10) and clicking on `purchase` should lead him to stripe checkout with automatically assigned price for the given amount of credits.

If pricing was standard in a way that one credit costs 1 EUR, and every subsequent credit costs 1 EUR as well, this would be easy as I would only provide one price ID (defined on Stripe) and I would pick up the quantity from the frontend.

Now the issue I have is that when I try to create session:

```
    $priceId = // id from Stripe. One of product prices

    $stripeSession = Session::create([
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'line_items'           => [[
            'price'    => $priceId,
            'quantity' => 1,
        ]],
        'mode'                 => 'payment',
        'success_url'          => route('stripe.success') . '/?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        'cancel_url'           => route('stripe.cancel')
    ]);
```

I am getting the error saying:

> Checkout does not support package pricing, aka `transform_quantity` in `line_items[price][0]

Can't seem to find that error in documentation, but even if I change quantity to 4 for second item, same thing happens.

```
'line_items'           => [[
    'price'    => // price ID for second option,
    'quantity' => 4,
]],
```

Also it is quite confusing as to what would this mean? The price for second item is already defined as being a package of 4, so does quantity 4 in this context mean that user would get 4x4=16 items?

How can I fetch packages in this context and know how much credits to give to the user given the need for gradual one time (non-recurring) pricing?

Comment: Unrelated:    7 EUR to get 10 credits  and 11 creadits  for 3 EUR + 4 EUR ?

Comment: It is a test Patrick, I didn't really do the maths :)

Comment: not quite getting what you do because no [mre] - but you can change this `'line_items' => [['price'    => $priceId, 'quantity' => 1,]]` to `'line_items' => [['price'    => $priceId, 'quantity' => 1],['price'    => $priceId, 'quantity' => 3],['price'    => $priceId, 'quantity' => 4],['price'    => $priceId, 'quantity' => 7]]` - not quite sure if the priceid can stay or needs a multiplier as well  - just weired ramblings though. you might need to provide a bit more context for sensible help - and php is not really my fortee ;o) - saw it through the vue.js tag

Comment: That doesn't work for the same reason. I gave a bit more context in the description. Can't really make minimal reproducible example as I am using external libs here both back and frontend

Comment: The error means that Checkout unfortunately just doesn't support Plans/Prices created this way : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/quantity-transformation which you must have done for creating the $priceId you're using. The workaround would be to calculate that transformation manually instead, or not use Checkout and integrate https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment directly instead.

Comment: I made a workaround doing exactly that, calculating prices on the fly. It is retarded because what's the purpose of defining prices if you can't use them...

Comment: My solution was to create different products with prices for packages. Then pass in metadata the total credits to add after a successful paid session. It's really sad you can't use package pricing with checkout sessions